# evaluate arithmetic expression of string literal

Tags: google-sheets

I want to show a multiple addition (the operands, not the result) in a cell, and use the result of the operation in another cell.

Is there a way to evaluate the literal expression dinamically?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()`, like this:

`=query(0, "select " & A2 & " label " & A2 & " '' ", 0)`

...where `A2` is the cell that contains the arithmetic expression you want to evaluate.

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#arithmetic-operators).